# Checking specific fields in a contact form

Tags: php, forms, field

In my contact form, I want to check to see if a field is empty. If it is, I'll return an error message.

However, I only want it to check certain fields, since not all of the fields I'm including are required.

```
    $fields = [
            'Company Name' => $_POST['companyname'],
            'Name' => $_POST['name'],
            'Email' => $_POST['email'],
            'Phone' => $_POST['phone'],
            'Comment' => $_POST['comment'],
        ];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
                if(empty($data)) {
                    $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
                }
```

How would I go about making exceptions for certain fields? I was thinking of adding required fields to a class, but perhaps there's another way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: `if(empty($data) && $field != '<excluded field name here>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another array with the fields that should be validated:

```
$validate = array('Name', 'Email');

$fields = [
    'Company Name' => $_POST['companyname'],
    'Name' => $_POST['name'],
    'Email' => $_POST['email'],
    'Phone' => $_POST['phone'],
    'Comment' => $_POST['comment'],
];

foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {
    if (in_array($field, $validate) && empty($data)) {
        $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
    }
}
```